# Full physical path of Composer vendor directory

Tags: php

Is there any way to get the full physical path of the Composer's vendor folder?

I have been searching internet for an hour but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use getcwd() function. Here you can read also regarding this http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: which is similar to `__DIR__`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a class within  the constant " `__FILE__`". just like following:

```
class ComposerPath{
    static  function  get(){
         return dirname(__FILE__);
    }
}
```

then you load it by composer,and use

```
CompoerPath::get();
```

Comment: Where i put the file? I need to get the path from my package.

Comment: you put your file in your directory  called "vendor"  ,  and you load the class same as other.  because `__FILE__` will be parsed before running.